# VirtualBox VM not starting after upgrade

Tags: virtualbox, debian-jessie

After upgrading virtualbox from 4.3 to 5.1 [using VB page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Trying to start a virtual machine gets 2 messages, that is clear about a driver version mismatch (`VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH`) and inviting you to execute `/sbin/vboxconfig`.

The loaded drivers are not the same version as VirtualBox

```
$ for i in `lsmod | grep box | cut -f1 -d' '`; do modinfo $i ; echo ; done
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/updates/dkms/vboxpci.ko
version:        4.3.36_Debian <-- should be 5.1.*
[...]
```

(I encountered this problem and didn't find the solution on the internet so I'm posting it here, hoping it helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for the drivers on internet, `/sbin/vboxconfig` builds them.

The problem was the old drivers were still present and preferred.

So I removed the old drivers and ran `/sbin/vboxconfig` again, this time it worked.
`sudo mv /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/updates/dkms/vbox* /tmp`
(Moving to /tmp instead of rm just in case)
The directory may vary, I found it in the first command in my question with lsmod then modinfo.

Then `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` and it should work

The new drivers are in `/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/misc/`

(No need to reboot.)